# Multidimensional Associative array email check

Tags: php

I have an array multidimensional associative array.

```
Array
(


[0] => Array
        (
            [username] => uname1
            [name] => fullname1
            [email] => uname1@email.com

        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [username] => uname2
            [name] => fullname2
            [email] => uname2

        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [username] => uname3
            [name] => fullname3
            [email] => uname3@email

        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [username] => uname4
            [name] => fullname4
            [email] => uname4@

        )

}
```

It should validate email address using the regular expression.The return array should consists of an array with only valid array.The array should be

```
Array
(


[0] => Array
        (
            [username] => uname1
            [name] => fullname1
            [email] => uname1@email.com
}
```

since [1,2,3] have invalid email address.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the answers is valid, and deserve some upvotes.  FWIW, I tried running each over 10000 iterations, and measured the elapsed time using `microtime(true)`.

- @Gumbo's solution, `array_filter()/filter_var()`: 0.631 sec.
- @Gordon's solution, `array_filter()/filter_var()` w/anon function: 0.620 sec.
- @mck89's solution, `array_filter()/preg_match()`: 0.307 sec.
- @Alexander.Plutov's solution, `foreach()/preg_match()`: 0.193 sec.

*edit:* I re-tested with [a more robust email regex](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) to apply a function on each value of an array and filter those values out where the function returns a false value. And to validate the email address, you can use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) in combination with [*FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL*](http://php.net/filter.filters.validate):

```
function filter_email($item) {
    return isset($item['email']) && filter_var($item['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
$filtered = array_filter($arr, 'filter_email');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- [`array_filter`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function

with a custom callback that removes all invalid eMails, e.g. something like

```
$filtered = array_filter($input, function($item) {
    return filter_var($item['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
});
```

**EDIT:** the above uses PHP 5.2's native [`filter_var`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate the eMail. Using the shown [anyonymous functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) requires PHP5.3. [See the chapter on callbacks for other types](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback*).

Answer (score 2):

Use array_filter:

```
<?php
function filtermail($item)
{
    return preg_match($EmailValidationRegexp, $item["email"]);
}

$filtered=array_filter($array, "filtermail");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   if (preg_match("/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/", $value['email'])) {
      $correct = $array[$key]; 
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to revisite your regex.

Comment: It is an example regex. Topicstarter answered about array.